# Cakephp - Proper way to return AJAX Success response?

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have been using the trick below to return success response with AJAX:

```
//In controller
echo 'success';

//In Javascript
if(response == 'success'){
    //redirect
    window.location.href = '/users/profile/';
}
```

It works fine on localhost. But in web server, I got the error below everytime I want to redirect the page after success:

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...
```

So yeah, I know it is caused by the `echo` before redirecting.

So, Is there proper way to return the success response? No need to be a message, just `true` or `false` is enough.

**[EDIT]**

By using `exit('success')`, it works fine, but is this the best way?

Thanks.

Comment: if your function handles ajax request then their is no need for any redirection..! could you show us the code... and you could do the redirection from JS part inside if( response == 'success' )... !

Comment: Hi thank you. Suddenly it works fine without changing any code. I thought using `exit('success')` fixed it, but I redo the change and it still works.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to redirect from javascript.

```
//In controller
echo 'success'; exit;

//In Javascript
if(response == 'success'){
    window.location = 'your-controller-action';
}
```

**EDIT**

You may have space `before/after php Opening/Closing tags in controller and models`. Remove all the closing tags from all controllers and models and any whitespace before opening tags. Then check the result.

Comment: Yeah, I use `window.location` to redirect, but it still gives me `Cannot modify header information`

Comment: @DarcCode That's a PHP error. It's not possible that a JavaScript redirect could give that message.

Comment: Hi, it suddenly works fine without any changes. I thought using `exit('success')` solves it, but I tried resetting the code and it's still fine. Thanks for your time